# Why is my code print out the same html link a lot of times?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

- I'm doing a following link activity on Python ( it's an assignment on Python Web Access Data - Coursera). Here is the problem:

- In this assignment you will write a Python program that expands on http://www.py4e.com/code3/urllinks.py. The program will use urllib to read the HTML from the data files below, extract the href= vaues from the anchor tags, scan for a tag that is in a particular position relative to the first name in the list, follow that link and repeat the process a number of times and report the last name you find.
- Actual problem: Start at: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Armen.html
  Find the link at position 18 (the first name is 1). Follow that link. Repeat this process 7 times. The answer is the last name that you retrieve.
  Hint: The first character of the name of the last page that you will load is: F

So I basically copy most of the code in the given link and come up with something on my own in the end. It looks like this:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import collections
collections.Callable = collections.abc.Callable
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
for i in range(7):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        tag = tags[17]
        link = tag.get('href', None)
        print(link)
    url = link
```

And I got the result: but it printed out like this:

http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Hailie.html
... ( it duplicates feel like a hundred of times)
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Hailie.html
...
http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Felicity.html

Which part of my code lead to this problem?
How can I cut it off?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the issue is printing information multiple times, so take a closer look in that part of code:

```
for tag in tags:
    tag = tags[17]
    link = tag.get('href', None)
    print(link)
```

Because you pick a specific position `tags[17]`, there is no need to loop over all the tags and print the same information over and over again in each iteration, so simply skip the loop:

```
tag = tags[17]
link = tag.get('href', None)
print(link)
```

*be aware, this will not cover the main task and the envisaged solution path, just your specific issue*

Comment: yooo it works. Thank you so much. I'm new to programming so I hope you don't mind about that silly question ( after reading your explaination I admit it a little bit (silly)). This is the first time I ask a question and I love the forum already. Thanks again bro

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem comes from your second loop on the tags, you don't need them, as you do it prints you the url as many times as there are `<a>`

```py
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import collections
collections.Callable = collections.abc.Callable
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
for i in range(7):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup('a')
    tag = tags[17]
    link = tag.get('href', None)
    print(link)
    url = link
```

This code should only give you the 7 url through which you will go

Comment: it's fine to not test the code if you are pretty sure about it. It works. Thank you for your help Devix